# A faster way to convert a large array from binary to decimal in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, binary

I have an array which consists of around 35 million (M) rows, each of which contain a 32 digit binary number. The idea of this portion of the code is to take each 32 digit row and convert it back to 3 separate decimal numbers, based on the their position within the binary digit. For instance, the first 8 digits are converted to the number 'yval' the next 8 are converted to 'xval' and the next 12 are converted to 'binval' This is currently in a for loop and runs around 35 million times - once for each row. It then outputs the decimal numbers into 'lidarcube'. Basically, Im wondering if there is a quicker way to do this? It currently takes around an hour to process and I would ideally like to cut this down. Apologies if this is poorly explained, im new to Matlab and coding in general.

```
for count = 1:M
   yval = 1+bi2de(no_frame(count,1:8));
   xval = 1+bi2de(no_frame(count,9:16));
   binval = 1+bi2de(no_frame(count,17:28));
   lidarcube(xval,yval,binval) = lidarcube(xval,yval,binval)+1;
end

save('test.mat','lidarcube')
```

Comment: It is indeed poorly explained. Can you give an example of the data? a [mcve]? In any case,   if you have a 32 digit binary data, and you are storing it as you seem to be (in `no_frame`) you are, at least, using 1 byte per bit. The smart thing is to do this as you are reading/loading `no_frame`, instead of loading all the data and the processing it.

Comment: What is `lidarcube`? Is it preallocated? What version of MATLAB are you on? `bi2de` is deprecated, there is a better function for that now: `bit2int` can do a whole array at once.

Comment: Also, Ander is right, why would you read individual bits? How do you read your data, and from where?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Apologies for my poor explanation. I have an image of the 'no_frame' array but im unsure as to how to upload it in a comment? Like I say, it consists of 35 million rows, each containing a 32 binary digit. A specific file type known as '.H5' is loaded in from the directory and is assigned to an array named 'data'. Various functions remove zeros, convert the array to binary, and get rid of any rows where the last digit is 1 (for specific reasons). This leaves the 'no_frame' binary data mentioned above. Bearing that in mind, at what point would you suggest to do this?

Comment: @CrisLuengo So Lidarcube is originally just a 3D matrix full of zeros and it is amended to in the for loop.  I'm on Matlab version R2021a. Does bit2int effectively do the same thing?

Comment: @spidersmotorbike you write is as code, but isntead of 35 million rows, you write 4 representative ones. A [mcve] starts with the word "minimal". I know what an h5 file is, but it would make no sense to store bits one by one, as that is not how computers work. If you have already functions that purge and clean up the data, you just need to add to them to make it reasonable. But again, we can only guess without a real example.

Comment: Ok, so if you read in the array as integers, you can do regular arithmetic, or use bitwise operators, to separate the three numbers out. Converting the whole array to separate bits is not the right way to do. Look for `bitand`, `bitshift`, and so on. These operate on the array as a whole.

Comment: Ref uploading an image, you should [edit] your question instead of adding lots of info in comments, and preferably you would use formatted code anyway, not images of data. Can you clarify you say you've got a 32 digit row, but it looks like you only use columns 1 to 28 in your example, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

For an 8 digit binary array, the decimal equivalent can be calculated by multiplying by the corresponding powers of 2 and summing the total. This can be easily implemented as a vectorised operation.

```
% generate some sample data
rng(0);
no_frame = randi([0,1],3,32); % 3 rows, 32 cols, all zero or one

% Define custom binary 2 decimal conversion function
fb2d = @(x) sum( x .* (2.^((size(x,2)-1):-1:0)), 2 );

% Calculate the decimal values in column blocks of 8
yval   = fb2d( no_frame(:,1:8) );
xval   = fb2d( no_frame(:,9:16) );
binval = fb2d( no_frame(:,17:28) );
```

The remaining loop is probably not too slow as long as `lidarcube` is preallocated.

```
for count = 1:M
   i_yval = 1 + yval(count);
   i_xval = 1 + xval(count);
   i_binval = 1 + binval(count);
   lidarcube(i_xval,i_yval,i_binval) = lidarcube(i_xval,i_yval,i_binval) + 1;
end
```

Comment: Matrix-vector multiplication like `x * [2.^((size(x,2)-1):-1:0)].'` is golfier (*and* linear-algebra-ier). [`polyval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) is also an option.